# Code in view does not update after rebuild in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Four domains are pointing to the same website, so to avoid having duplicate content I wrote this code at the beginning of `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@if (!Request.Url.Host.Contains("example.com"))
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com" + Request.Url.AbsolutePath, true);
}
```

Then I realized that it also redirects on localhost, so I changed the code to:

```
@if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("localhost") && !Request.Url.Host.Contains("example.com"))
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com" + Request.Url.AbsolutePath, true);
}
```

But on localhost it still redirects. to make sure I completely removed the code,
tried **Build**, **Rebuild**, **Clean then Rebuild**, **Remove dll files** and no luck. The solution build is successful the solution is built and not using the old build.

Why the removed code still works?

Comment: Did you try clearing browser's cache?

Comment: @Berkay cache of what?

Comment: is the same behavior for incognito mode also?

Comment: @IoanaStoian no actually worked in incognito mode. but this makes me even more confused. why (& how) can server-side code be cached in browser?

Comment: view is rendered as html, so browser might be displaying the cached html again

Comment: I think `AND` operator is wrong. It will be always generate `true`. Both conditions won't be true at the same time, one of them will be always false `(!false will be true)` and Response will be redirected all the time. Try using `OR` operator.

Comment: @Berkay abi, and operator is correct there, but as you suggested. I should have cleared the cache

Comment: In browser press `Ctrl` + `F5` when you do view related changes!

Comment: @ViVi I know that. As the code was server-side code I didn't know that it also needs clearing the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing browser's **cache** will solve the problem.